# How to escape a space on OSX in a Weblogic startup script

Tags: macos, bash, escaping, space

Here is the problematic portion of the script:
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/Users/tipton_g/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea12/jr-ide-idea/lib/jrebel/jrebel.jar $JAVA_OPTIONS"

The "Application Support" directory is not found because the space is not recognized.  Unfortunately, in this case neither Application\ Support nor "Application Support" (in quotes) works since the entire argument is a string.

One suggestion was that I just make a symlink to the file, but I'd like to find out if there's a way to escape the space when the entire thing is already inside quotes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try with `JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:"/....."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making a symlink to the file and referred to the symlink in the script.  Seems to work fine, if a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [ZIP archive](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/prev-releases) of JRebel and extract it into directory that doesn't include whitespace. In fact this is what JRebel IntelliJ plugin is doing if you start the container from IDE with JRebel agent - it copies jrebel.jar into a temporary folder which doesn't include a whitespace in the path so there wouldn't be any troubles with escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes around the path:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:'/Users/tipton_g/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea12/jr-ide-idea/lib/jrebel/jrebel.jar' $JAVA_OPTIONS"
```

However unless `$JAVA_OPTIONS`
 is used inside double-quotes in any further scripting, you will encounter this issue again.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still the output: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : '/Users/tipton_g/Library/Application

Comment: Well then the script that uses `$JAVA_OPTIONS` is broken as it doesn't use double-quotes.